# Convergence of the series $1+a+ab+a^2b+a^2b^2+\dots+a^nb^{n-1}+a^nb^n+\dots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Consider the series $$1+a+ab+a^2b+a^2b^2+\dots+a^nb^{n-1}+a^nb^n+\dots (0<a<b)$$
>   1. Use Ratio test to prove that the series converges when $b<1$ and diverges when $a>1.$
>
> 2. Will the Ratio test give any conclusion of $a<1<b$

Attempt:
I got

$$\overline\lim\limits \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=b$$
$$\underline\lim\limits \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=a$$

series converges if $b<1$ and diverges if $a>1$

Please help for second part of the question.

Answer (score 4):

The ratio test is inconclusive if $a < 1 < b$.  To demonstrate this from the definition of the ratio test depends on the definition of *the ratio test* you are working with, but it **must be inconclusive**.

This is because we can produce values $a < 1 < b$ for which the series exhibits either behavior, i.e. just knowing that $a <1 <b$ is not enough information to know whether the series converges or diverges.

Grouping pairs of terms in the series, we can write it as

$S(a,b) = (a+1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (ab)^n$

Fix any $0 < a < 1$, so $\frac{1}{a} > 1$

If we choose $1 < b < \frac{1}{a}$, then $ab < 1$ and the sum converges, but if we choose $b > \frac{1}{a} > 1$, then $ab > 1$ and the sum diverges.

Answer (score 2):

If your definition of the ratio test matches [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test),  the article explicitly mentions the case where $a \lt 1 \lt b$ and says that the test is inconclusive.  Check your definition of the ratio test, but I think it will agree.  You can show that (assuming $a,b \gt 0$) if $ab \lt 1$ the series converges and if $ab \gt 1$ the series diverges but you weren't asked for that.

Comment: "a<1<b  .... the test is inconclusive" please explore it, (not from the theorem of Ratio test). Also about $ab<1$ case you have mentioned, it is known to me and that can be proved by Cauchy ratio test.

Comment: @user1942348 :the question you posted just asked whether the ratio test could be used.  The version of the ratio test that I cited cannot be used.  I followed up with the point about $ab \le \gt 1$.  What exploration are you looking for?

Comment: why for a<1<b .... the test is inconclusive

Comment: It has to be inconclusive because of what I said at the end.  Either $a$ or $b$ could dominate.  The test itself says it is inconclusive if the $\lim sup \gt 1$ and the $\lim \inf \lt 1$